# How to read Bayesian Table?

Tags: bayesian

I was looking at here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network

At first table and first row there is a value **0.4.**

**Is that R|S or S|R ?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0.4$ is the probability of sprinkler being used given that it does **not** rain.  $\Pr(S \text{ true} | R \text{ false})$ if you like.

Similarly, $0.6$ is the probability of sprinkler **not** being used given that it does **not** rain.  So adding them together give $1$, since given that it does not rain, the probability the sprinkler is used or is not used is $1$.